# Retrieve child nodes of specific schema type from input control

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a legacy document with some additional schema based tags in it:

```
<td class="inputControl">
    <input id="OffsetAccountsRequired_R0" type="radio" name="OffsetAccountsRequired_N" value="Y" >Yes
        <tla:instruction type="unhide" value="OffSetAccountsApp1"></tla:instruction>
        <tla:instruction type="jscript" value="//Irrelevant JavaScript here"></tla:instruction>
    </input>
    <input id="OffsetAccountsRequired_R1" type="radio" name="OffsetAccountsRequired_N" value="N">No
        <tla:instruction type="hide" value="OffSetAccountsApp1~OffSetAccountsAppls1and2"></tla:instruction>
    </input>
    <input id="OffsetAccountsRequired_R2" type="radio" name="OffsetAccountsRequired_N" value="" checked="true" class="hiddenRadio" onclick="validate_js(this)">
        <tla:instruction type="hide" value="OffSetAccountsApp1~OffSetAccountsAppls1and2"></tla:instruction>
    </input>
</td>
```

and some dreadful JavaScript called by the validate_js(this) event that works on those tags:

```
// Calling line - in this case 'obj' is the input control 'OffsetAccountsRequired_R2'
tlaInstructions = getInstructionTags(obj, 'tla:instruction');

function getInstructionTags(inputID,tagType){
    var coltla;
    var coltlaArray = new Array();
    tagType = tagType.toUpperCase();

        var tlaFinished = false;
        coltla = inputID.parentNode.childNodes;
        for(var i=0;i<coltla.length;i++){
            if(coltla[i].nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT' && coltla[i].id == inputID.id){
                for(var j=i;j<coltla.length;j++){
                    if(coltla[j].nodeName.toUpperCase() == tagType){
                        coltlaArray[coltlaArray.length] = coltla[j];
                    }

                    if(coltla[j].nodeName.toUpperCase() == '/INPUT'){
                        tlaFinished = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(tlaFinished){
                break;
            }
        }

        return coltlaArray;
    }
}
```

My task is to bring this JavaScript up to spec so that it will work in IE9 (it was previously only ever used in a vb6 web browser control).

As far as I can tell with my limited JavaScript skills what the code is meant to do is retrieve all the tla:instruction nodes from within the input element. It does this using the line `coltla = inputID.parentNode.childNodes`

Which looks very odd as it's going up a level and then down a level. I assume that it does this because retrieving the tla:instruction elements doesn't retrieve the nodes if you simply use `coltla = inputID.getElementsByTagName('tla:instruction')`.

Is there a simpler way to retrieve an array of elements of a specific type from within an input control?

Comment: I've tried to simplify as much as possible while retaining enough detail to be useful. Let me know if additional detail is required

Comment: JQuery is the simpler way :)

Comment: Unfortunately JQuery is not an option.

Comment: Because it's a legacy system that requires approval for changes from a third party and I'm not allowed to add useful stuff willy-nilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the HTML spec [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) tags cannot have any content.

> Start tag: required, End tag: forbidden

So, they get attached to the parent of the input element hence the reason why `inputID.parentNode.childNodes`

here is a simplified version using `nextSibling`

```
function getInstructionTags(inputID,tagType){
  var coltla;
  var coltlaArray = [];
  tagType = tagType.toUpperCase();

  var tlaFinished = false;
  var next = inputID;
  while ( !tlaFinished ) {
    var next = next.nextSibling;
    tlaFinished = next == null;
    if ( !tlaFinished ) {
      var nodeName = next.nodeName.toUpperCase();
      if ( nodeName == tagType ) {
        coltlaArray.push(next);        
      } else {
        tlaFinished = (nodeName != '#TEXT');
      }
    }
  }
  return coltlaArray;
}
```

Comment: The way that the mixed HTML/XML legacy documents have been developed without adhering to any standards is causing endless problems.